# Will ubuntu import all important files?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, files, transfer, 13.10

This is actually a question for later when Ubuntu 13.10 comes out but I couldn't wait... I am asking when ever you upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 or any version will all your important files transfer? I am still a bit new to Ubuntu and I started out with Ubuntu 13.04 so I am a very new ubuntu-er.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually whenever you **upgrade** an existing installation all the files you keep in the `/home` directories will be kept untouched. This includes not only your personal documents, but also application settings, desktop appearance, e-mail accounts, browser preferences and history.

But note the word *"usually"* above. There never is a guarantee that it will work in 100% of cases (imagine a power failure during upgrade...).

It is therefore best advice to

> [**Backup all data in your home directory**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

prior to a distribution release upgrade. I always do that.

Answer (score 1):

As long as nothing in your home directory is removed or damaged, most apps will usually do a best-effort attempt to use the configuration and data under it.

The OS itself doesn't care about home directories, usually only `/etc`. Those files are usually a little more flexible, but it will still try to a certain extent.